# Hiding/Showing properties and ordering properties in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am about to upgrade our software from ASP.NET WebForms to .NET MVC.  All over the web it shows how to create a view based on a model, which is fine.

In this project the users can hide properties of the model to generate a view suitable for them, yet another client in another website and hide other properties.

The code is all the same, but i would like to know if there is a way to hide/show properties of a model based on a condition easily, hopefully without having a lot of IF statements all over my views.

Example - How can 1 client see only name and town, yet another client see all 3 properties.  Just need to show based on a condition.

```
public class MyObject() {

    public property name { get; set; };
    public property town { get; set; };
    public property customText { get; set; }

    public MyObject() {}
}
```

NOTE: Users can also determine the order of these properties, can i do that as well easily ?

Just to say that creating separate views is not possible.  The above is a very simple example of a model with properties.  Our models can have about 100 properties, and the user can turn these on and off whenever they like, so it needs to be able to be done dynamically

Is there a way of creating a ViewModel on the fly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: well you can create seperate view and on the base of role show specific view

Comment: you can filter your model e.g. at the controller, and send this "filtered" model to the view. For example you can create database table where each user maps the number of properties you want to render with them, then in controller access this database and build your model object accordingly to the information you obtained from the db.

Comment: Building an object model (dynamic) sounds interesting.  Do you have a simple example, or a link where i can see this?

Comment: Think i have actually found something here http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/09/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/

Comment: If you want to use a "dynamic model" using an `ExpandoObject` then just use `ViewBag`, it's an `ExpandoObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Property` class or similar and model you data appropriately:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool Visible {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;}
}
```

Then your view model can be similar to your example:

```
public class ViewModel 
{        
    public Property Name {get;set;}
    public Property Town {get;set;}
    public Property CustomText {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: How is this a good solution?  Wouldnt you have to populate the View with lots of If statements to see if it should write the property?

Comment: You could just write display and editor templates for the "Property" type and put the logic in there, once. Then all you would need in your view is `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot bind multiple models to your view.Obviously you have to do workaround in your view based on user roles.
Or else create a seperate model and view for each user roles.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a project called Dynamic MVC.

http://dynamicmvc.com

It currently does not do what your asking.  The functionality is already there, it is just not exposed the way you need it.  However, if you are interested I will add the functionality so you can pass the properties you want to display in the querystring.  Eventually, a customizable dynamic view will generate your page for you without any coding required.  Also, the order of the properties would determine the order on your page.  This would work for any model with the DynamicEntity attribute.

Let me know if your interested and I can include it in the next release.

Comment: Chris spumds interesting. That would be good. Send me a link and i can download and try it. Thabks

Comment: I created a work item for this on codeplex (https://dynamicmvc.codeplex.com/workitem/1645).  I released version 1.1.0 on nugget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicMVC/1.1.0).  You can follow the instructions in the readme file to get started.  It might be best to test it out in a new project.  If you have already specified a controller for an entity, it will not get routed to the dynamic controller.  You can get the functionality by calling the controller yourself or inheriting from dynamic controller.  Also see tutorials on http://www.dynamicmvc.com/Tutorial.

Comment: Please leave feedback/issues here https://dynamicmvc.codeplex.com/discussions/566755.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will need to specify the properties you want to display by passing them in the querystring as "ViewProperties = Name, Town".

Comment: I can have a lot of properties to show. Can u do it via a properties instead of querystring?

Comment: I am assuming you are displaying a list of models.    Currently if you only need to customize this once a design time you can specify this by setting the IndexProperties on the DynamicEntity attribute.  You can also set this property at runtime from the controller in the appropriate action method like so: DynamicEntityMetadata.DynamicEntityAttribute().IndexProperties = "Name, Town";

Comment: You might be interested to know if you wanted to update some of the properties but not others you can do this with the DynamicEdit view and the EditProperties property of DynamicEntity.

Comment: You should set the IndexProperties property at the beginning of the Index and _Index actions.